# Is it possible to have mixed source control providers in a VS2010 solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, visual-sourcesafe-2005

Currently most of the development in the company I work for is controlled via VSS.  I've installed Team Foundation Server for the development at our site.

There is a future project that will involve new developement, but referencing older code bases hosted in VSS.  My preference would be to use TFS for the new development, but I'm unsure if a VS2010 solution can have projects using different source control providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change the source control provider manually (unbind - change SCC provider - bind) each time.

Comment: too bad ... this should be automated !

Answer (score 0):

No Visual Studio does not allow for mixing source control providers within a solution at the same time.